# Game of Life - Printing board to the same position

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int board[10][10] = {{0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0},
                     {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
                     {0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                     {0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0},
                     {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
                     {0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};

void PrintBoard()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if(board[i][j] == 1)
            {
                cout << '*';
            }
            else
            {
                cout << '-';
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    bool done = false;
    while(!done)
    {
        done = false;
        PrintBoard();
        int i = 0;
        i++;
        cout << i;
    }
}
```

My problem is printing the board to the same position on the console. This way it prints a hundreds of boards in a line downwards on the console. I want it to be an endless loop for now because when I get the future generations part working then it will fluidly move like you'd expect the program to.

Comment: use `setw` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/

Comment: Also this might help: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/3207/

Comment: @40two I doubt that's solvable using `setw()`, it depends at least which capabilities the actually terminal offers.

Comment: This would depend on the terminal you are using; and only be vaguely related to c++.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I know but it will also help him that's why I didn't delete it.

Comment: simplify your program to the problem you are actually trying to solve.  Printing two lines repeatedly in the same place.  (One line is easy, just use \r at the end.)  Look into cursor-positioning escape codes on the console you are using.   When you get the simple version working, apply the solution to the actual program.  If you have trouble getting the simple version working, ask much simpler question here (or do some searching for previous answers!)

Comment: You should consider using ncurses.

Comment: @FinalContest I don't see any answers in that question that answer this one. This question is about rewinding the cursor position to print over previous output. That question and all its answers are about how output gets blitted to the screen. If the idea was to tell him to use terminal commands, then that really isn't clear from the duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in a windows terminal it appears that 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Windows_and_DOS 
will help.

```
char csi_esc = 27;
char csi_begin = '[';
// clear screen and reposition cursor
cout<<csi_esc<<csi_begin<< "2J]";
```

might work as a start. (Untested, I don't have access to a windows terminal).

Oops, I read the wiki article very poorly.

> The Win32 console does not natively support ANSI escape sequences at
>   all. Software such as ANSICON[7] can act as a wrapper around the
>   standard Win32 console and add support for ANSI escape sequences.
>   Otherwise software must manipulate the console with the ioctl-like
>   Console API[8] interlaced with the text output. Some software
>   internally interprets ANSI escape sequences in text being printed and
>   translates them to these calls.[9]

So instead you should use the regular WinAPI calls.

```
#include<windows.h>

void PrintBoard(){
    // Position cursor at 0,0
    HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = coord.Y = 0;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition( console, coord );
    // Draw the rest of the stuff. 
}
```

See [Using High Level Input and Output Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686974%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  and the [API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073%28VS.85%29.aspx)

If you are in a terminal in a unix based system just

```
#include<ncurses.h>
```

and link the library

```
g++ -o life life.cpp -lncurses
```

Comment: This just makes another line appear after the previous output "<-[2J]1" but doesn't make the cursor go back to the top of the screen. Perhaps I've asked this wrong or something. What I want to happen would be similar to how a buffer and back buffer work so I would want it to refresh the screen yet print the board again to the same place that it was originally printed to.

Comment: @user3255112 Indeed, I read the wiki article incorrectly and added some Win32 calls.